# Error: Apprate is not defined in hybrid app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to hybrid app development. After installing APK, when I opened the app, it always show a white screen. Then I debug the app in chrome, and in the console I got the following error.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app 
due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module 
function ($cordovaAppRateProvider) due to:
ReferenceError: AppRate is not defined
at Object.setPreferences 
(file:///android_asset/www/lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js:7:1562)
at Channel.<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/debug/app.js:2311:45)
at Channel.subscribe (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:775:21)
at document.addEventListener (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:133:34)
at HTMLDocument.document.addEventListener (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1703:13)
at file:///android_asset/www/debug/app.js:2301:26
at Object.invoke (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17995:19)
at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17899:45
at forEach 
(file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13691:20)
at loadModules
```

I am stuck with this error for the past 2 days and I didn't get a solution of the real problem.

Comment: It is not able to find Provider `$cordovaAppRateProvider` OR may be library inclusion  is missing.